# Return value to an Object reference

Tags: java

I'm new to Selenium java and currently learning object reference and returns

I was trying to code this logic wherein I declare a non static variable in main class, declare an object for it, use that object in another class and return it to main class

My problem is when i return it back to main class it outputs 0. Is this scenario possible? or am I doing something wrong

```
package ReturnType;

public class Class1 {
    public int Mul(int i, int j) {
        Class2 cc = new Class2();
            cc.c=i*j;
            return cc.c;

    }
}
```

Here is my main class

```
package ReturnType;

public class Class2 {
    public int c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 xp = new Class1();
        Class2 cc = new Class2();
      xp.Mul(2,3);
      System.out.println(cc.c);
     }
}
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return value from `xp.Mul`. Where do you expect it do go and why?

Comment: Also, none of the code here has anything to do with Selenium.

Comment: The `cc` in `Class1` and `Class2` refer to different instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost got the result... the return of the method is getting lost, you have to assign it to something

```
public class Class2 {
    public int c;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 xp = new Class1();
        Class2 cc = new Class2();
      cc.c = xp.Mul(2,3);  //here assign it
      System.out.println(cc.c);
     }
}
```